# Solr DataImportHandler: Can I get a dynamic field name from xml attribute with XPathEntityProcessor?

Tags: solr, dataimporthandler

I have some XML to ingest into Solr, which sounds like a use case that is intended to be solved by the DataImportHandler.  What I want to do is pull the column name from one XML attribute and the value from another attribute.  Here is an example of what I mean:

```
<document>
  <data ref="reference.foo">
    <value>bar</value>
  </data>
</document>
```

From this xml snippet, I want to add a field with name `reference.foo` and value `bar`.  The DataImportHandler includes a XPathEntityProcessor for processing XML documents.  I've tried using it and it works perfectly if I give it a known column name (e.g, `<field column="ref" xpath="/document/data/@ref">`) but have not been able to find any documentation or examples to suggest either how to do what I want, or that it cannot be done.  So:

- Can I do this using XPathEntityProcessor? If so, how?
- If not, can I do this some other way with DataImportHandler?
- Or am I left with writing my own import handler?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I haven't managed to find a way to do this without bringing in a transformer, but by using a simple `ScriptTransformer` I worked it out.  It goes something like this:

```
...
<script>
function makePair(row) {
  var theKey = row.get("theKey");
  var theValue = row.get("theValue");

  row.put(theKey, theValue);
  row.remove("theKey");
  row.remove("theValue");

  return row;
}
</script>

...

<entity name="..." 
  processor="XPathEntityProcessor" 
  transformer="script:makePair"
  forEach="/document"
  ...>

  <field column="theKey" xpath="/document/data/@ref" />
  <field column="theValue" xpath="/document/data/value" />
</entity>
...
```

Hope that helps someone!

Note, if your dynamicField is multivalued, you have to iterate over theKey since row.get("theKey") will be a list.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is select the node keying on an attribute value.

From your example, you'd do this:

```
<field column="ref" xpath="/document/data[@ref='reference.foo']"/>
```

Comment: This is helpful if you already know what the value of `ref` is that you're looking for.  In my case, I don't know that value so I can't put it in the `xpath` attribute.  Thanks though!

Comment: Oh, I see. Sorry it wasn't helpful for you, but glad you figure it out.